# VB6 ADO ConnectionString Property with ; or " as values

Tags: sql, vb6, ado

I have to support an older component which is written in VB6.
The componenent has methods to access the database via ADO Recordset.

Now I run into an error while I found out that someone uses a semicolon in a password.
As semicolon is a reserved character it needs to be escaped.

Found this resource: 
http://www.connectionstrings.com/formating-rules-for-connection-strings/
and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms722656(v=vs.85).aspx

So I tried add this code:

```
Private Function MaskString(ByVal p_sVal)
  Dim l_sString As String
  Dim l_sQuote As String
  l_sQuote = """"
  l_sString = p_sVal
  If InStr(1, l_sString, """") > 0 Then l_sQuote = "'"
  If InStr(1, l_sString, ";") > 0 Then l_sString = l_sQuote & l_sString & l_sQuote
  MaskString = l_sString
End Function
```

So I call this function for each value and the final connection string then is like:

```
provider=sqloledb;database=data_base_name;server=server_name;uid=sa;pwd="test;password"
```

Used like:

```
AdoConnection.ConnectionTimeout = lConnectionTimeout
AdoConnection.ConnectionString = strConnectionString
AdoConnection.Open
```

However this seems to be correct now, but VB6 Ado give me the following error now:

```
Method OpenDB: -2147467259 - Ungültiges Attribut für die Verbindungszeichenfolge - Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
```

(Probably english is like - Invalid attribute for the connection string - )

So old VB6 doesn't support this? Or how do I escape those reserved chars then?

Comment: You can use `AdoConnection.Open strConnectionString, strUserID, strPassword` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `Password` keyword instead of `pwd`

```
provider=sqloledb;database=data_base_name;server=server_name;uid=sa;Password="test;password"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you pass the semicolon using chr(59) it might help ? Also lookout for the double quotes.

```
Connection string = "provider=sqloledb" & chr(59) & "database=data_base_name" & chr(59) & "server=server_name" & chr(59) & "uid=sa" & chr(59) & "pwd="""test" & chr(59) & "password"""
```

Comment: That won't make a difference, the result is a string with semicolons inside.